# Package dependencies cannot be resolved Ubuntu 14.04 vlc-audacius

Tags: 14.04, package-management, dependencies, vlc, audacious

```
vlc: Depends: vlc-nox (= 2.1.4-0ubuntu14.04.1) but 2.1.4-0ubuntu14.04.1 is to be installed

     Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15) but 2.19-0ubuntu6 is to be installed
     Depends: libfreetype6 (>= 2.2.1) but 2.5.2-1ubuntu2.2 is to be installed
     Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but 1:4.9-20140406-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
     Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4 is to be installed
     Depends: libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4 is to be installed
     Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.6) but 4.8.2-19ubuntu1 is to be installed
     Depends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.3.3) but 1:1.2.8.dfsg-1ubuntu1 is to be installed

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

    audacious: Depends: libaudclient2 (= 3.4.3-1) but 3.4.3-1 is to be installed
           Depends: libaudcore1 (= 3.4.3-1) but 3.4.3-1 is to be installed
```

Answer (score 5):

The following is the code which I used to install vlc on my ubuntu 14.04:

Removing old vlc and its packages: `sudo apt-get purge vlc vlc-nox gstreamer1.0-libav:i386 libavcodec-extra-54:i386 libavformat54:i386 libopus0:i386`

Adding architecture: `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`

Then install vlc: `sudo apt-get install vlc`

Answer (score 0):

It means you have unmet dependencies for a lot of software that is already installed. Run "sudo apt-get -f install" to fix that and allow the installation of more software

Comment: simiris@simiris:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.


and after that

Comment: sudo apt-get install audacious
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

Comment: audacious : Depends: audacious-plugins (>= 3.4.3) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: run "sudo apt-get install audacious-plugins"

Comment: the same sbegeron, thanks but nothing works...

Comment: thanks to
http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.ubuntu.xubuntu.user/6690


it worked with me:

finally worked for me 

sudo apt-get install aptitude
sudo aptitude install vlc
--> Y --> Y

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps:

sudo apt-get purge vlc vlc-nox

sudo apt-get install vlc

Let us know.

Comment: unfortunatelly nothing

Answer (score 0):

I had nearly the exact same package dependency problems and figured out wine installed packeges for i386 architecture on my i686 system. Removing this packages

- gstreamer1.0-libav:i386
- libavcodec-extra-54:i386
- libavformat54:i386
- libopus0:i386

solved my problem and I was able to install vlc again using `apt-get`.

Answer (score 0):

I also had same problem and it got resolved after I ran 
   `sudo apt-get purge vlc vlc-nox`
    
--> This has Purged configuration files for earlier installed vlc

later it got installed after said dependencies installed ..with below command
`sudo apt-get install libpostproc52 vlc-nox vlc`

Hope this helps.

Subbarayudu A.

Answer (score 0):

`aptitude` is able to resolve the dependency problem by running:

```
sudo aptitude install vlc
```

The actual conflict is the package `libpostproc-extra-52`, which can be resolved by running

```
sudo apt-get purge libpostproc-extra-52
sudo apt-get install vlc
```